# sklearn SVC + sparse data speeding up

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis

Good day!

I have a big trouble because SVC takes too much time. And I can't normalize data, because it is sparce and size of matrix is too big for dense representation. I scaled data by

```
sklearn.preprocessing.scale
```

but it isn't enough. What is possible to do for speeding up calculation of SVC?

Comment: Normalizing works for sparse matrices, mean-centering (`sklearn.preprocessing.Scaler`) does not. Try a linear learner, maybe with an [approximate kernel](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.nl/2012/12/kernel-approximations-for-efficient.html).

Comment: Normalization often means mean centering, or mean centering and then divided by the standard deviation. That was clear from the context as it would indeed destroy sparsity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Buy a machine with such a stupidly huge amount of RAM that you can cache the whole gram matrix. Cache size has the biggest performance impact on LibSVM, which is what scikit learn uses.

2) Use a different algorithm. Scikit learn is already calling out to LibSVM, which is probably the fastest SMO based SVM implementation available.